# Databricks, How to update value of a column with MAP data-type in a delta table using a python dictionary and SQL UPDATE command?

Tags: sql, dictionary, apache-spark, databricks, updates

I have a delta table in Databricks created by:

```
%sql
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev.bronze.test_map (
    id INT,
    table_updates MAP<STRING, TIMESTAMP>,
 
  CONSTRAINT test_map_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
  
  ) USING DELTA
LOCATION "abfss://bronze@Table Path"
```

With initial values:

```
INSERT INTO dev.bronze.test_map 
VALUES (1, null), 
       (2, null), 
       (3, null);
```

Note that there is no value in column "table_updates".

[image]

After processing other tables in our platform, I have table updates info as a python dictionary like below:

```
table_updates_id1  =  
 
{'id1_table_1': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 4, 33, 22, 323000),
 
 'id1_table_2': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 4, 33, 22, 323000)}
```

[image]

Now, I want to update the value of column "table_update" where id=1 using "SQL UPDATE command" (note that I want to update the table not dataframe).

I tried different methods but failed.

**1st trial:**

```
spark.sql(f"""
UPDATE dev.bronze.test_map
SET
    table_updates = map({table_updates_id1})
WHERE
    id = 1
""")
```

**Error:**

[image]

**2nd trial:**

```
spark.sql(f"""
UPDATE dev.bronze.test_map
SET
    table_updates = map('{','.join([f'{k},{v}' for k,v in table_updates_id1.items()])}')
WHERE
    id = 1
""")
```

**Error:**

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
f"""map('{','.join([f'{k},{v}' for k,v in table_updates_id1.items()])}')""")
```

results in:

```
map('id1_table_1,2023-03-26 04:33:22.323000,id1_table_2,2023-03-26 04:33:22.323000')
```

which is indeed a single string inside 'map'. You need to quote each value:

```
f"""map({','.join([f"'{k}','{v}'" for k,v in table_updates_id1.items()])})"""
```

That yields:

```
map('id1_table_1','2023-03-26 04:33:22.323000','id1_table_2','2023-03-26 04:33:22.323000')
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I get an error: 

"[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near ''2023-03-26 21:30:31.704000''(line 4, pos 34)

== SQL ==

UPDATE dev.bronze.test_map
SET
    table_updates = 'id1_table_1','2023-03-26 21:30:31.704000','id1_table_2','2023-03-26 21:30:31.704000'"

Is it because of the data-type since I pass string instead of timestamp?

Comment: I missed 'map(...)' in my answer - fixed it now, have a look.